# Underfull hbox with tblr

Tags: environments, tabularray

I do not understand why this generates a `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)` warning:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytblr}{+b}{
\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={X[1]X[2]}, measure=vbox, row{1} = {gray8,font=\bfseries}, stretch=-1, rowsep=4pt, row{2-Z} = {font=\footnotesize}}
    #1
  \end{tblr}
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{mytblr}
Case & Description \\
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I dont have error . I have good results. Here I can't add a screenshot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `%` missing at the end of l.11. Without it, the unprotected line ending will act like a space, making your new environment too wide to fit in a single line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mytblr}{+b}{%
\noindent\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines, colspec={X[1]X[2]}, measure=vbox, row{1} = {gray8,font=\bfseries}, stretch=-1, rowsep=4pt, row{2-Z} = {font=\footnotesize}}
    #1
  \end{tblr}%
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{mytblr}
Case & Description \\
A & B \\
C & D \\
\end{mytblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been a tricky one for me…

Comment: I wonder if this behaviour shouldn't be corrected in the tabularray package, to avoid this warning when there is no text afterwards.

Comment: @leparc It is standard latex behaviour, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. I do not think I've ever experienced this impact in such a significant way before using tabularray.